# Serial readBytes - Arduino Loop

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a loop that reads the serial port for 1 byte. When it finds a valid byte it calls other functions.

This works but it also seems to run the else statement as well.

```
void loop() {
byte rx_byte[1];
byte input[2]; 


if (a_Serial.available() > 0) {    
    a_Serial.readBytes(rx_byte,1); 

    debug_Serial.println(rx_byte[0],HEX);

    if (rx_byte[0] == 0xaa){

             debug_Serial.println("aa Running");

            }

    if (rx_byte[0] == 0xbb){
            debug_Serial.println("bb Running");

            }

    if (rx_byte[0] == 0xcc){
              a_Serial.readBytes(input,2);
              rawcmd(input);

              }

    else {
      a_Serial.println("Error");
      debug_Serial.println("Command Invalid");}

     memset(rx_byte, 0, sizeof(rx_byte));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `else if` instead of `if`. If your `rx_byte[0]` isn't equal to `0xcc` then it can also be `0xaa` or `0xbb`.

```
if (rx_byte[0] == 0xaa){

         debug_Serial.println("aa Running");

        }

else if (rx_byte[0] == 0xbb){
        debug_Serial.println("bb Running");

        }

else if (rx_byte[0] == 0xcc){
          a_Serial.readBytes(input,2);
          rawcmd(input);

          }

else {
...
```